# How to add array within another array in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want the output in this format:

```
abc: [
       { a:' ', b:' ',
         c:[ {c1:' ', c2:' '}, {c1:' ', c2:' '}, {c1:' ', c2:' '}]
       },

       { a:' ', b:' ',
         c:[ {c1:' ', c2:' '}, {c1:' ', c2:' '}, {c1:' ', c2:' '}]
       }
]
```

For this output, I am trying this query:

```
db.test.aggregate(

{
    $group:
    {
        _id: "$clientId",
        abc:{
            $push:{
                "a":"$a",
                "b":"$b",
                c:{
                    $addToSet:{ 
                        "c1":"$c1",
                        "c2":"$c2"
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using this I am only getting C array in the result array and not A and B values.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Your data does not help your question, empty values like this are easy to misinterpret. What are you expecting to merge? Just unique values in the c array or put everything together? It really would be clearer for everyone if you edited your answer with 1. Some values in the fields, 2. Show what you expect to get as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is need to use two group by clauses in aggregation framework as we cant make two arrays within the same group block.

Following is the query to have the desired output:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {$group:{
        _id:{"a": "$a","langName": "$b"},
        c:{$addToSet:{ 
            "c1":"$c1",
            "c2":"$c2"
            }}
        }

        }
    ,
    {$group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            abc:{$addToSet:{
               "a":"$_id.a",   //gets the upper a element of _id of above group
               "b":"$_id.b",
            c:"$c"     // gets the full array that has been formed in the above group by.
            }
        }        
    }
    }
    )
```

I have been trying to use $a instead of $_id.a thats why i was facing the problem.
This query solved my problem. :)